# transparent navigation bar css

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website and at the top of the site i have a navigation bar that stays at the top of the screen as you scroll. Here is a sample image of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/11bni.png

The problem it, when I scroll down, some (but not all) text is visible through the navigation bar and makes it illegible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPafV.png

Here is the code for the:

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="pull-left">
      <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="./tools.html">Tools</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pull-right">
      <li><a href="./about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav a:hover {
    background: #e1e1e1;
    color: black;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
```

I have already tried changing the opacity but that made it illegible 100% of the time. I am willing to try any suggestions that you have. Thank you!

Comment: try setting z-index on the .nav to 99, see if that helps

Comment: I just tested your code and everything looked fine, so the issue is probably that you have something on your page with a z-index greater than the z-index of your nav. You can supercede this by making your nav z-index unbelievably high, such as 100000000000.

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm! Turns out the other container elements were the ones on top of it!

Answer (score 0):

Check the z-indexes you use in your website and make sure to give the .nav the heigest z-index, that should solve the problem. Do it like this:

```
.nav {
    z-index: ...;  /* higher amount than used somewhere else */
}
```

Let me know if that works or not!

Answer (score 0):

Your nav and the rest of the page are likely on the same 'layer' which is mish-mashing them together when they overlap. Try adding a `z-index` to `.nav` to place it 'above' the rest of the page. The `z-index` number will need to be 1 higher than the current highest `z-index` on your page (if no other element has a `z-index`, that would be 1).

```
.nav {
  z-index: 1;
}
```